# Extracting and exchanging terms within an R formula object

Tags: r

I would like to create a graphing function in R which takes a formula as an argument, e.g.:

`my.plot(sqrt(Sepal.Width) ~ Petal.Width + log(Petal.Length) + Species + Petal.Width * Petal.Length, .data = iris)`

And then

1. Perform a model fit with the first predictor term exchanged for another vector created within the function.
2. Use the outcome term and the first predictor term for an overlying plot.
3. Allow interaction and crossing terms, and use of the `.` symbol denoting all other variables in the data frame.
4. Handle the case where only 1 predictor term is provided - e.g. `Sepal.Width ~ Petal.Width`.

R pseudocode for a highly simplified example:

```
library("formula.tools")
my.plot <- function(.formula, .data) {
  outcome.term <- lhs(.formula)
  first.predictor.term <- rhs(.formula)[1]
  new.formula <- outcome.term ~ 1:nrow(.data) + rhs(.formula)[-1]
  my.fit <- lm(new.formula, data = .data)
  my.predict <- predict(my.fit)
  plot(first.predictor.term, outcome.term, data = .data)
  lines(first.predictor.term, my.predict, data = .data)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could accomplish the same using Base R:

```
my.plot <- function(.formula, .data) {
  outcome.term <- deparse(.formula[[2]])
  first.predictor.term <- .formula[[3]]
  len <- length(first.predictor.term) > 1
  if (len) first.predictor.term <- .formula[[3]][[2]]
  if (len) .formula[[3]][[2]] <- substitute(new_variable)
  else .formula[[3]] <- substitute(new_variable)
  
  .data['new_variable'] <- 1:nrow(.data)
  
  my.fit <- lm(.formula, data = .data)
  my.predict <- predict(my.fit)
  f <- reformulate(deparse(first.predictor.term), outcome.term)
  plot(f, data = .data, ty = "p")
}
```